# What's the best Stack Exchange site for asking questions about supplement interactions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I know about [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) but I don't think that it fits the bill for the kind of questions I'm referring to. Let me give you an example:

> Some people recommend avoiding sulforaphane on workout days, because they say it could cancel the benefits of exercise. Is that so?
>
> Sulforaphane is a compound found in broccoli sprouts.

Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask this sort of question?

Answer (score 4):

[Physical Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) seems like the right site for such a question. Specifically, looking through its ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page, it explicitly states that questions about "nutrition as it relates to exercise" are appropriate for the site.